# SQL Update using Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

I have to add a contacts name to an assignments table by querying the contacts table.

`Contact` table:

```
 ID     First_name     Last_Name
 -----------------------------------
 1234   John           Jones
 9876   Mary           Smith
```

`Assignment` table

```
 ContactID   Name
 -----------------
  1234
  9876
```

Using this query I get

> *Subquery returned more than 1 value.*

Query:

```
 update A  
 set Name = (select  distinct first_name + ' ' + last_name from contacts c join        Assignments A on c.id = A.contact_id where A.contact_id = c.id)
 from Assignments  A 
 join contacts c on c.id = A.contact_id
 where c.id = A.contact_id
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JOIN` them directly, like so:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Name = c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name
FROM Assignments a
INNER JOIN Contacts c  ON c.id = A.contact_id
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, I knew I was over thinking it. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Update A
Set A.name = c.First_name + ' ' + c.Last_name
From Assignment A JOIN Contacts C ON A.ContactID = C.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a subselect

```
UPDATE A  
   SET Name = c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name
FROM Assignments  A 
JOIN contacts c 
   ON c.id = A.contact_id
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Name = c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name
FROM Assignments a
INNER JOIN Contacts c  ON c.id = A.contact_id
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!